# change "fakeroot debian/rules binary" output dir

Tags: installation, debian, package-management

I am building debian packages and I'd like the new package to be delivered in the project root folder `.` instead of in `../`
Is there anyway of doing it without overriding debian/rules dh_builddeb? Ideally with a parameter to fakeroot, but I don't see how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Debian Policy Manual](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-source.html#s-debianrules):

> [The binary target] should then create the relevant binary package(s), using `dpkg-gencontrol` to make their control files and `dpkg-deb` to build them and place them in the parent of the top level directory.

So you should be able to put the package somewhere else by writing a wrapper around `dpkg-deb` and putting it ahead of `/usr/bin` on the `$PATH`. `dh_builddeb`, which is the most common way of causing the binary package to be build, does call `dpkg-deb` through `$PATH`.

However putting the build products in the toplevel directory seems risky to me. If you're not careful, they may end up in a source package or diff.